# MS SQL Server multiple column sort independently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

So to get things out of the way, due to structure i'm left in a situation of trying to sort some columns of data in SQL in a way that is evading me.
The problem is that i need multiple sets of 2 columns sorted independently, For example i have something like this:

> ```
>    Name | Val1 | Name | Val2 | Name | Val3
>    A    |  2   | A    | 1    | A    | 3
>    B    |  1   | B    | 3    | B    | 2
>    C    |  3   | C    | 2    | C    | 1
> ```

and i need the table to be sorted by the highest of each value:

> ```
>    Name | Val1 | Name | Val2 | Name | Val3
>    C    |  3   | B    | 3    | A    | 3
>    A    |  2   | C    | 2    | B    | 2
>    B    |  1   | A    | 1    | C    | 1
> ```

I don't seem to know how to organise using ROW_NUMBER() and various other things i have done through long searches being able to separate out individual columns for ordering but i don't know how i can keep two linked while the others sort independently, Can anyone help? 
EDIT:
The Data is Extrapolated from one table after calculations had been done for their values.
So say i have my table of:

> ```
>    Name | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | 
>    A    |  2   | 1    | 3    | 
>    B    |  1   | 3    | 2    |
>    C    |  3   | 2    | 1    |
> ```
>
> The values are names specifically are just used for example, but are wildly Differing values.
>   So from that table of final results i need to get the results in the format that the name with the highest value will be on top for each individual value
>          SELECT Name AS N1,
>          Val1,
>          Name As N2,
>          Val2
>    etc
>   EDIT: Example:
>
> ```
>    Name1|Units|Name2|Units| Name3|Units
>    AF   |218  |AF   |0.83 | AF   |1.04
>    AD   |172  |AD   |0.49 | AD   |1.05
>    AF   |116  |AF   |0.87 | AF   |1.06
>    AF   |324  |AF   |0.84 | AF   |1.10
> ```

Comment: Do you *really* have 3 columns named `[name]`? A table can't have 2 (or more) columns with the same name. Is this actually 3 different tables, not 1?

Comment: They're pulled from a table getting the overall Data, then created a sub table from that in the desired format, so i am able to get the first table example given but i am having trouble getting it sorted appropriately
Edit: So for exmaple, although the list of names are the same, they for exmaple Name1, Name2

Comment: How do you get the first table?

Comment: Select Name As N1,
    Val1,
     Name AS N2,
    Val2,
    Name AS N3,
    Val3
   From tbl

Comment: Seems that the data the OP has supplied us is not representative of their real data, based on their comment below *" However this data is for a "league" table as sorts, so the numbers are just for an example but can vary wildly so the table can't be joined on the value as they go to 2 decimal places"*. Thus this question is impossible to answer at the moment.

Comment: i do apologise, with the unclear explaination, what would make it any easier knowing the values can be any range between 0 and 100,000? just that said values are associated with the specific names

Comment: Provide us data representative of your data, in the form the data is in.

Comment: YOu said in your below comment *"so the numbers are just for an example but can vary wildly so the table can't be joined on the value as they go to 2 decimal places"*. You're supplying an `int`. Which is correct? If they aren't ints, and we can't perform a `JOIN` on these values, why are you supply an `int` value which is a clear `JOIN` candidate?

Comment: I do apologise, what i was trying to convey is that the numbers themselves need to be independently ordered from highest to lowest, and to keep the corresponding name to said value, so i believed the numbers in question were irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, consider the following approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #NameValue (
    Name varchar(10),
    Val1 int,
    Val2 int,
    Val3 int
)

INSERT INTO #NameValue 
VALUES
    ('A', 102, 201, 303),
    ('B', 101, 203, 302),
    ('C', 103, 202, 301);

WITH nv1 AS (
    SELECT Name, Val1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Val1 DESC) AS RN1
    FROM #NameValue
),
nv2 AS (
    SELECT Name, Val2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Val2 DESC) AS RN2
    FROM #NameValue
),
nv3 AS (
    SELECT Name, Val3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Val3 DESC) AS RN3
    FROM #NameValue
)
SELECT 
    nv1.Name AS Name1, nv1.Val1, 
    nv2.Name AS Name2, nv2.Val2,
    nv3.Name AS Name3, nv3.Val3
FROM nv1
LEFT JOIN nv2 ON (nv1.RN1 = nv2.RN2)
LEFT JOIN nv3 ON (nv1.RN1 = nv3.RN3)
```

Output:

```
Name1   Val1    Name2   Val2    Name3   Val3
C       103     B       203     A       303
A       102     C       202     B       302
B       101     A       201     C       301
```

Comment: PERFECT! thank you very much :D i had been close to this but couldn't sort it in my head properly